# Which hidden folder in my home folder contain the data for the Passwords and Keys application?

Tags: password, keyrings, hidden-files

I made a fresh install of Precise Pangolin beta from Oneiric. I saved my home folder on an external drive. Now I want to copy passwords and keys to the new installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folder in the Home folder is:

```
~/.gnupg
```